# Prove that function is monotonic?

Tags: derivatives, monotone-functions

I need to show that the real valued function $\frac{\log(x)}{\log(x + \sqrt{x^2 - 1})}$ is a monotonic function. I tried using $x = sec(\theta)$ but I can't seem to prove that the new derivative is positive.

Also, $x \gt 1$

Comment: what is your  $f'(x)$?

Comment: Why don't you answer to @Boris ?